# How do I know that these two dates are in the range of start date and end date? (PostgreSQL)

Tags: postgresql, date

How do I know that these two dates are in the range of start date and end date?

for example, I have data in the database as follows:

| id | start_date | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-11-07 09:00:00 | 2022-11-07 16:00:00 |
| 2 | 2022-11-08 10:00:00 | 2022-11-08 12:00:00 |

```
Input:
start_date : '2022-11-07 08:00:00'
end_date : '2022-11-07 09:00:00'
```

if I input the data above, it means the data is not in the range right? but when I use this query, the data is still in the range

```
SELECT
    start_date,
        end_date,
FROM
    table
WHERE
    (start_date >= '2022-11-07 08:00:00' AND start_date <= '2022-11-07 09:00:00')
    OR 
    (end_date >= '2022-11-07 08:00:00' AND end_date <= '2022-11-07 09:00:00')
```

Would you like to help me? Thank you in advance.

I want to get the right query for range between two dates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to deal with ranges is to use a [range type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html)

```
select *
from the_table
where tsrange(start_date, end_date) @> tsrange('2022-11-07 08:00:00', '2022-11-07 09:00:00');
```

The `@>` is the "contains" operator and is true if the left hand range completely includes the range on the right hand side.

The above will create ranges that *exclude* the upper value. If the ending time should be *included* use e.g. `tsrange(start_date, end_date, '[]')`

---

Alternatively you can use the standard compliant `overlaps` operator:

```
select *
from the_table
where (start_date, end_date) overlaps (timestamp '2022-11-07 08:00:00', timestamp '2022-11-07 09:00:00');
```

I am however not 100% that both solutions behave the same, especially with edge cases.

Comment: thank you so much, it turns out the `overlaps` one meets my criteria in determining if two dates is in range or no